# How to get relations with sub relations in laravel?

Tags: laravel, sqlite, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8

If I am getting User::with('persons')->get(); in laravel8
my persons table has another relation with other table 'comment' how can I fetch User with person and person relation comment in a single line?
what is the best practice to do it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading

Comment: I am not asking for docs I want code

Comment: that is the code to do it in the example   https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading  its called Nested Eager Loading

Answer (score 0):

I actually didnt quite understand if the user has two separate relations with `person` and `comment` or if user has a relation with `person` which has a relation with `comments`.

If it is the first one this is the solution:

`User::with('persons')->with('comments')->get();`

If it is the second one this is the solution:

`User::with('persons.comments')->get();`

Comment: in the first example you can do `with(['persons', 'comments'])` btw  :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 User::with('persons'=>function($query){
               $query->with('comment');
           })->get()
```

the callback function should return the relation in persons model